# Problema ao renderizar corretamente um select HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

Tenho a seguinte tag `select`:

```html
<select asp-for="@Model.EstadosServicos" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<EstadoServico>()" id="tipo" class="form-control"></select>
```

que cria este painel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este HTML renderizado no navegador gera este código contendo, automaticamente, o atributo `multiple="multiple"`:

```html
<select id="tipo" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="EstadosServicos">
    <option value="0">Inicial</option>
    <option value="1">Intermediário</option>
    <option value="2">Cancelado</option>
    <option value="3">Final</option>
</select>
```

Na inspeção de elemento, ao retirar o `multiple="multiple"` ele então muda para o formato de `select` que preciso.

A questão é: como escrevo meu HTML de maneira que ele crie o `select` como na figura abaixo? Ou mesmo, o que devo fazer para que o atributo `multiple="multiple"` não seja considerado ao renderizar a página?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio não ter como fazer isso, porque o comportamento do select sem o `multiple` é diferente do com o atributo. Uma possível solução é usar JavaScript para manipular o select de forma que ele tenha a aparência que vc quer e ao clicar nele, ele possa aceitar múltiplas seleções.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você usar `JQuery` pode colocar o código na sua página.

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tipo').removeAttr('multiple');
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Oi Victor, isso funcionou exatamente como eu precisava. Obrigado!